# Navigation Bar 100% Width Centering

Tags: css, html, navigation

I've been trying for a while now to center everything that's in my Navigation Bar. Here's my CSS and HTML code I would appreciate it if anyone could give me a hint on what to do.

```
#cssmenu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


#cssmenu li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#cssmenu a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
}
#cssmenu a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#cssmenu {
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #232323;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  width: auto;
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 15px;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  color: #a0a0a0;
  font-family: Verdana, 'Lucida Grande';
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 70px;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  -webkit-transition: color .15s;
  -moz-transition: color .15s;
  -o-transition: color .15s;
  transition: color .15s;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  padding: 16px 0 20px 0;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  top: 55px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -90px;
  width: 180px;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s .1s;
  -moz-transition: all .3s .1s;
  -o-transition: all .3s .1s;
  transition: all .3s .1s;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > ul {
  opacity: 1;
  top: 65px;
  visibility: visible;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  border-color: transparent transparent #fafafa transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
#cssmenu > ul ul > li {
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a {
  color: #323232;
  font-family: Verdana, 'Lucida Grande';
  font-size: 13px;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  padding: 5px 8px 7px 16px;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 0.1s;
  -moz-transition: background-color 0.1s;
  -o-transition: background-color 0.1s;
  transition: background-color 0.1s;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a:hover {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: -16px;
  left: 206px;
  padding: 16px 0 20px 0;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  text-align: left;
  width: 180px;
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  -moz-transition: all .3s;
  -o-transition: all .3s;
  transition: all .3s;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
#cssmenu ul ul > li:hover > ul {
  opacity: 1;
  left: 190px;
  visibility: visible;
}
#cssmenu ul ul a:hover {
  background-color: #cc2c24;
  color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

And finally my HTML.

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li class='active'><a href='index.html'><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Forums</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Title1</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Title2</span></a></li>
   <li><a href='#'><span>Title3</span></a></li>
   <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Title4</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Currently all that happens is my navigation bar is 100% width which is what I want but, the buttons are still aligned to the left and I want them to be in the center. I've tried numerous things and can't seem to make it work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need this :

```
#cssmenu > ul {
  display:table;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

View the demo **http://jsfiddle.net/sn3Hn/2/**

Comment: Thanks that seems to have done the job! :) Also one final question, how would I make the position of the Navabar fixed? So that if I scroll down the Navbar stays at the top?

Comment: Jus set your `#cssmenu` with `position:fixed` and `top:0`... Also your conten need to have a margin-top equal to the height of the menu to prevent the overlap.

Comment: I've just done that and now the Navbar has gone to 50% width O.o

Comment: Make a fiddle with your issue then i can help you

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/FwR5w/ It fixes the text only but the black background doesn't fix

Answer (score 0):

Use same structure, but you need change your css:

```
#cssmenu ul 
{
   text-align: center;
}    

#cssmenu li   
{
  display: inline-block; < Secret;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Codepen > http://cdpn.io/usChr

Resolve? 
*Good lucky*

Answer (score 0):

I've had success using the css table method.

```
#cssmenu ul {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

#cssmenu ul li {
  display: table-cell;
}
```